# How to show that two Hermitian tridiagonal matrices are similar?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, hermitian-matrices, similar-matrices

Given two tridiagonal hermitian matrices A,B with $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_i\in \mathbb{C}$ as follows
\begin{align} 
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1} & |b_1| & \cdots & 0  \\
  |b_1| & a_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots & |b_{n-1}|  \\
  0 & 0 & |b_{n-1}| & a_{n}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1} & b_1 & \cdots & 0  \\
  \overline{b_1} & a_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots & b_{n-1}  \\
  0 & 0 & \overline{b_{n-1}} & a_{n}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

is there any way to show that the matrices have the same eigenvalues? I want to use the property that they are similar but I don't now how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $b_j = |b_j|e^{i \theta_j}$ for $j = 1,2,...,n-1$ and perform the unitary similarity $B \mapsto DB\overline{D} = A$, in which $D$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal unitary matrix
$$
   D = \operatorname{diag}(1,e^{i\theta_1},e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)},e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3)},...)
$$

Comment: Use MathJax formatting